# Concluding that the effect is not zero from a one-tailed test

Tags: self-study

There's an unclear sentence in the Online Stat Book, [Chapter 11.5](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/logic_of_hypothesis_testing/tails.html):

> Some have argued that a one-tailed test is justified whenever the researcher predicts the direction of an effect. The problem with this argument is that **if the effect comes out strongly in the non-predicted direction, the researcher is not justified in concluding that the effect is not zero**. Since this is unrealistic, one-tailed tests are usually viewed skeptically if justified on this basis alone.

Could somebody provide a simple example? It's hard for me to imagine what this phrase is about.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing I test a new wonder drug and am convinced it will be better that treatment as usual so I decide to do a one-sided test. Now suppose that it makes people substantially worse. The logic of one-sided tests forces me to remain silent about this even though scientifically and ethically I would want to report it.